# Submit Data in Google Sheet using Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to submit data on request form sheet to data sheet.

Request Form Sheet
[image: snapshot1]

Data Sheet
[image: snapshot2]

I did try this code:

```
function submitRequest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("req_form"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("data"); //Data Sheet
  
  // Get the input values for the form
  var requestNumber = formSS.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var dateNeeded = formSS.getRange("C5").getValue();
  var dateRequested = formSS.getRange("C6").getValue();
  
  // Get the items from the form and store them in an array
  var items = [];
  for (var i = 3; i <= 33; i++) {
    var item = [
      formSS.getRange("E" + i).getValue(),
      formSS.getRange("F" + i).getValue(),
      formSS.getRange("G" + i).getValue()
    ];
    // Check if the item has any value, if yes, add it to the items array
    if (item.join("") !== "") {
      items.push(item);
    }
  }
  
  // Add the input values and items to the data sheet
  var startingColumn = 1;
  var range = datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow() + 1, startingColumn, 5, items[0].length + 3);;
  range.setValues([["Request Number", "Date Needed", "Date Requested", "Item"], [requestNumber, dateNeeded, dateRequested, ""]].concat(items));

  formSS.getRange("C4:C6").clearContent(); // Clear the project name and date requested
  formSS.getRange("E3:G32").clearContent(); // Clear the item rows
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Request Submitted !!');
}
```

But I get error like this:

Error

```
Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 4 but the range has 6.
submitRequest   @ Code.gs:28
```

I'm stuck. I am self studying appscript, so there are things that I can't solve as of now. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result from your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result? By the way, where line is your error in your script? I couldn't understand the error line from `Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 4 but the range has 6. submitRequest @ Code.gs:28`. I apologize for this. First, I would like to correctly understand your current issue and question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why is there an error message:**

`The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 4 but the range has 6.`

The range is declared with this line:
`var range = datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow() + 1, startingColumn, 5, items[0].length + 3);;`

- The number of columns is the last attribute: `items[0].length + 3`. This equals **6**.
- Items is an array which (in a loop and based on an `IF` statement) can have three values pushed onto it.

The data is set with this line:
`range.setValues([["Request Number", "Date Needed", "Date Requested", "Item"], [requestNumber, dateNeeded, dateRequested, ""]].concat(items));`

- The number of columns of data = **4**
- `["Request Number", "Date Needed", "Date Requested", "Item"]`
- `[requestNumber, dateNeeded, dateRequested, ""]`

---

**Fixing the script**

- get the number of rows of material data
- get all the material Data, qty and remarks in a single pass using `getDateRange`
- assume the "data" header row is already created
- loop through each row of the material data and identify the values for Material, qty and remarks, **then** push an entire row onto the array

---

```
function submitRequest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("req_form"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("data"); //Data Sheet

  // Get the input values for the form
  var requestNumber = formSS.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var dateNeeded = formSS.getRange("C5").getValue();
  var dateRequested = formSS.getRange("C6").getValue();

  // get the number of rows of material data
  var eVals = formSS.getRange("E4:E").getValues();
  var eLast = eVals.filter(String).length;
  // if no data then stop
  if (eLast == 0){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No material data !!');
    return
  }

  // data on req_form
  var formRange = formSS.getRange(4,5,eLast,3)
  var formData = formRange.getValues()

  // loop through the data and append to the array
  var items = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <eLast; i++) {
    var itemName = formData[i][0]
    var qty =  formData[i][1]
    var remarks = formData[i][2]
    items.push([requestNumber, dateNeeded, dateRequested, itemName,qty,remarks]);
  }

  //Add the input values and items to the data sheet
  var startingColumn = 1;
  var numCols = 6
  var dataLR = datasheet.getLastRow()
  var dataRange = datasheet.getRange(dataLR + 1, startingColumn, items.length, numCols);
  dataRange.setValues(items);

  // clear content
  formSS.getRange("C4:C6").clearContent(); // Clear the project name and date requested
  formRange.clearContent(); // Clear the item rows
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Request Submitted !!');
}
```